# Spring Security to support multiple authentication provider LDAP authentication and JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to implement an authentication and authorization service for an ongoing spring-boot project. I have implemented a JPA based authentication provider and it is working fine. How do I add LDAP authentication provider to the same project and switch between the authentication methods depending on the user authentication type?

Below is my code

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UsernamePasswordAuthProvider authProvider;
    @Autowired
    private LdapAuth ldapAuth;
    @Autowired
    private LdapAuthenticationpopulator ldapAuthenticationpopulator;


    private String ldapUrls = "ldap://localhost:3890";
    private String ldapSecurityPrincipal = "cn=admin,dc=mycompany,dc=com";
    private String ldapPrincipalPassword = "admin";
    private String userDnPattern = "uid={0}";
    @Autowired
    private UsernamePasswordAuthFilter usernamePasswordAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Order(1)
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls)
                .managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal)
                .managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword)
                .and()
                .userDnPatterns(userDnPattern)
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthenticationpopulator);
    }

    @Override
    @Order(2)
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.addFilterAt(usernamePasswordAuthFilter,
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Though my LDAP credentials are correct it is not reaching that method.
How do I get the authentication method from DB ex(LDAP, JPA, SSO) for my application and execute the corresponding auth provider method?

I have gone through multiple documents for MultipleAuthenticationProviders but I couldn't find much clarity
Please let me know if there is any possible solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you could get rid of configureGlobal and add the ldap info in the configure method: `auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider).ldapAuthentication()....;`

Comment: tried that as well earlier it is first going to ```auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider)``` and it will give an error of bad credentials.  and then the request will come out of execution due to exception.

Comment: I think you need to return null from the first auth provider if user and password are not present so that next auth provider in the chain can authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution to this. I have put up LDAP enabled or JPA auth enabled properties in DB and loading them at run time depending upon the boolean value I'm calling the particular auth method.